# running a command line application outside of its folder (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-interface

I've done this once before and have forgotton.

I need to run for example

```
c:/myfolder/anotherfolder/app.bat
```

from anywere i.e

```
c:/app.bat or c:/genericfolder/app.bat or c:/thisfolder/app
```

is it setting environment variables?

Comment: because im looking for a command line expert! granted it should be windows tags only. - deleted.

Comment: You need to add `c:\myfolder\anotherfolder` to the `PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the location of the app to your "PATH" environment variable.